# How to load records inDB to window formC s

Tags: c#

I am trying to load records (Gender) from my database to my window form so that it loads automatically as the form loads, am having challenges with it, because it's only getting the ID from the database and not the Gender name, how do i do it?
Below is the code snippet i coded it with

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Load_Gender();
}

public void Load_Gender()
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost;" +
      "Initial Catalog=DemoDb;Integrated Security=true; User Instance=False";

        SqlConnection connection = new lConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;

        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Gender";
        SqlDataAdapter sl = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sl.Fill(ds, "Table");

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Table"];

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            string id = row["Id"].ToString();
            string genderName = row["GenderName"].ToString();
        }

        // Loading RECORDS to comboBox
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            comboBoxGender.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
        }
    }
    catch()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Need to see table DDL to make sense of this one.

Comment: `Rows[i][0]` is the first column containing *Id* - just change to `Rows[i][1]` to get the *GenderName* from the second column.

Comment: try to use comboBoxGender.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString());

Comment: The first `foreach` seems totally irrelevant, it reads all rows and does nothing with the result.

Comment: Thanks very much, it worked. Am grateful

Comment: @FagbemiBabs Please mark an answer as correct when you are done with your questions

Answer (score 2):

Your foreach loop essentially is doing nothing, unless you put that in for debugging to check what each row contains although you could do that just inspecting the data table definition in memory.

```
comboBoxGender.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
```

This code is only grabbing the Id, hence the Rows[i][0], the 0 is the first column.

Rows[i][1] is the gender name.